# JSON string requested using AJAX from WCF service missing .d and __type attributes

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, jquery

I am using jQuery AJAX to call a WCF service. The service retuns a JSON string that represents an instance of a custom object.

What I'm writing is meant to replace some current functionality in an existing project. I first wrote a demo project to make sure my new code worked without exposing it to the trappings of the exisiting project. The demo project returns a JSON string formated as `{"d":{"__type":"MyObject", "Attribute1":"Value"...}`.

Once I had the demo working perfectly, I moved the code into the existing project. The JSON now returns a JSON string formatted as `{"Attribute1":"Value"...}`. The `".d"` and `"__type"` attributes are missing.

I actually make use of the `"__type"` attribute, so not having it returned is a problem. I've read that the `".d"` attribute was a new addition to ASP.NET 2.0, so my initial thought is that the exisiting project is using an earler version. However, in the examples I've seen of this, the `"__type"` attribute did exist in the earlier ASP.NET versions, and I've also upgrated the project to .NET 4.0 without any resolution.

Where did the attributes go, and how do I get them back?

Comment: Assuming you couldn't get them back naturally via the framework, could you not derive and add these values to your object in the WCF service before it is converted to a JSON string?

Comment: Thatt's definitely a viable option, but I'd really like to understand what is happening.

Comment: Do you changed contentType, responseFormat or requestFormat in js call or at definition?